# Where clause doesn't limit records when aggregate used in select

Tags: mysql, join

I have this select in my MySQL DB:

```
select r.ID, r.ReservationDate, SUM(p.Amount) AS Amount
from Reservations r
join Payments p
on r.ID = p.ReservationID
where r.ConfirmationNumber = '123456'
and p.CCLast4 = '3506'
and r.ID = 54321
```

It gives me exactly 1 record -- the correct record -- as expected. But if I change the `CCLast4` (3506) to any old number/string I want, I still get the record back, but Amount is null. I would expect no record at all because the where clause no longer matches. If I change the the `ConfirmationNumber` or the `ID`, as expected I get back no results. But `CCLast4` is being completely ignored.

If I remove the aggregate: `SUM(p.Amount) AS Amount` - all is good, and the `CCLast4` demands the correct number before returning the string.

I don't understand why the aggregate causes the where clause related to the `Payments` table (`CCLast4` column) to be ignored.

*How can I change the query so that I can use the aggregate in the select AND all the where clauses are honored?*

Comment: Substituting `p.Amount` for `SUM(p.Amount)`: with correct `CCLast4` value, I get a record and a valid amount - with wrong `CCLast4` value, I get no record back as expected. The `SUM()` is causing the `CCLast4` where clause to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the expected behaviour. From [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html):

> Without GROUP BY, there is a single group and it is nondeterministic which [non-aggregated column] value to choose for the group.

Although not very clearly stated, this means that you always get *one* group (so one row), even for an empty table.

It is also worth emphasizing that the values that MySQL chooses for the non-aggregated columns in your `select`, `r.ID` and `r.ReservationDate`, are in fact nondeterministic and will specifically vary across MySQL versions (e.g. they will usually be `null` for MySQL 8.0 while they will usually contain existing values for earlier versions).

The solution is similarly subtle - add a `group by` (so the quoted sentence does not apply anymore):

```
...
where r.ConfirmationNumber = '123456'
and p.CCLast4 = 'xxx'
and r.ID = 54321
group by r.ID, r.ReservationDate
```

should give you 0 rows.